# What does git core.commentChar=auto do?

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm testing `git commentChar=auto` with `git-commit` for a library that must emulate `git-commit` for some purposes.

If I run `git commit -m "#message"`, and then make a second commit which open the editor to edit the message,
comments are still marked by `#`. Why is this?

According to the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corecommentChar):

> **core.commentChar**
>
> Commands such as commit and tag that let you edit
>   messages consider a line that begins with this character commented,
>   and removes them after the editor returns (default #).
>
> If set to "auto", git-commit would select a character that is not the
>   beginning character of any line in existing commit messages.

But when I run a test script:

```
git config --global core.commentChar auto
touch foo
git add foo
git commit -m '#message'
touch bar
git add bar
git commit # opens editor, And I see:

# Please enter the commit message // Wrong! This should not use the # char.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [some tests in the git repo](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/t/t7502-commit.sh#L590-L614) it only applies this "auto" methodology if the message it is "commenting" about already contains a comment character.  The *existing commit messages* in the docs refer to (in this case) the amended message (or in the case of a rebase-squash the several commit messages).

You can see the way this is handled in [commit.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/117ddefdb4dfd9b40ae60967a7327754d8ce7a87/builtin/commit.c#L799-L800): [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/117ddefdb4dfd9b40ae60967a7327754d8ce7a87/builtin/commit.c#L631-L659)

It looks at the current buffer that is about to be displayed and picks the first of `"#;@!$%^&|:"` as potential comment characters and otherwise errors.

Answer (score 3):

When it says "existing commit messages", it doesn't mean messages for *previous* commits; it would be impractical to check all previous messages. It means a character that's not already in use in the *current* message before invoking the editor. That might seem redundant — why does it need to check for anything if you haven't written the message yet? But there are lots of ways to have an existing message, including:

- You're doing `git commit --amend`.
- You're doing a `git merge` and the message is pre-populated.
- You have the `commit.template` configuration variable set or are using the `--template` option to `git commit`.

Whatever the case, the purpose of `core.commentChar = auto` is to scan the pre-existing message for line-beginning characters and choose one that won't conflict.